# Handling an empty Golang gorilla/mux vars

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I have the following controller function that is supposed to delete an item within a collection. I am using the `gorilla/mux` package. The problem arises when I try to handle the case where the user forgot to send an id on a DELETE request.

`localhost:8000/movies/` or `localhost:8000/movies`

While an example of the proper request would be

`localhost:8000/movies/3`

Although `params["id"]` is empty, the execution never goes into the else block. I am not sure why.

```
func (c Controller) Delete(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var error Error
        params := mux.Vars(r)

        movieRepo := movieRepo.MovieRepository{}

        if _, ok := params["id"]; ok {
            id, err := strconv.Atoi(params["id"])

            if err != nil {
                error.Message = "Server error"
                utils.SendError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, error)
                return
            }

            rowsDeleted, err := movieRepo.delete(db, id)

            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            successMessage(w, rowsDeleted)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("errrr..")
            error.Message = "Id is not present."
        errorMessage(w, http.StatusBadRequest, error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how the endpoint is registered on the router:

```
router.HandleFunc("/movies/{id}",controller.Delete(db)).Methods("DELETE")
```

Comment: I suspect that's because the patterns, under which you registered the handler, don't match the request paths, however without seeing the code that registers that handler it's hard to tell. That is, if you registered the handler X only under `/movies/:id` then a request to `/movies` or `/movies/` will never trigger that handler X because the path does not match the pattern.

Comment: mkopriva, please see the edit above. Thanks.

Comment: That confirms my suspicion, basically you don't have to handle the case where no id is provided because the gorrila/mux will never call your handler for such a path. Instead it will automatically return a 404 error, which is the correct error.

Comment: ... However, if you want to handle such requests yourself then you'll just need to register the handler twice, once for `/movies/{id}` like you already do, and once for `/movies`, and then gorrila/mux will execute your handler when a request to `/movies` is made.

Comment: It looks like you have more handlers for ```/movies...```. @mkopriva is right, ```mux``` will not call ```Delete(db *sql.DB)``` handler for ```/movies/``` path.

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the help.